# maxi-pod heat store keeps putting water back into header tank

Tags: hot-water

my maxipod has worked perfectly well since installed in 2014 but now it has started to put hot water into header tank then out the overflow.  I turned of water going out from header tank to maxipod and then hot or should i say luke warm water came out expansion pipe into header tank. NOW i have no hot water or heating what can i do?

Comment: problem solved i had a combi boiler converted but somehow a pressure balancing pipe with a tap somehow magically open a little putting pressured water into hot tank  thanks for comments.

Comment: please provide and accept your findings as an answer so that the question can be resolved. [Take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if I'm not making sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check for internal coil leaks. excess water is being supplied to the maxi-pod from somewhere. Also check with the installing contractor and the manufacturer for the warranty coverage provided. You said " it started to put hot water into the header tank"; what is the header tank? If the  header tank is isolated then that part of the system is probably ok. Check for problems elsewhere. My recommendation; if a system is too complex, too new, or too sophisticated, it is probably not a good buy unless it comes with a very good long term warranty including parts and labor. I prefer the older "tried and true" systems. What is the sources of heating to the Maxi-Pod; solar, wood/coal stove, conventional central heating system, etc. Lastly can you isolate the Maxi-Pod and return to the conventional heating system until repairs are completed?